# Компиляция less кода в простой стиль

Tags: html, css, less

Как сделать чтобы мой `less` код компилировался в простой стиль?

```css
@myqwrty: red;
h1 {
  color: @myqwrty;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="style.less" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="less.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque odio amet neque praesentium rerum qui sunt, tempora iure hic a harum, quae et veniam unde consequatur, cupiditate? Consectetur, ducimus, praesentium.</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну либо вы ручками собирайте less в css `lessc styles.less styles.css`

Либо используйте Gulp/Webpack и прочее для отслеживания и компиляции.
Браузер не делает компиляции, ему нужно давать уже готовый css.

Answer (score 0):

Надо выполнить команду

```
lessc styles.less styles.css
```

прежде чем вы используете

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы на Windows. Есть утилита - [WinLess](http://winless.org/)